# If $L:\mathsf{C}\rightleftarrows\mathsf{D}:I$ are functors $L\dashv I$ with $I$ fully faithful, then $L\eta=\eta L$

Tags: category-theory

Let $L\dashv I:\sf D\to C$  be an adjunction, where $I$ is the inclusion of the full subcategory $\sf D$ into $\sf C$; denote the unit and the counit respectively by $\eta$ and $\epsilon$. I'm asked to  prove that $L\eta=\eta L$.

I'm not sure to understand the task: $L\eta$ is an arrow in $\sf D$, while $\eta L$ is not  well-defined, as $L:\sf C\to D$, so I suppose that it is meant $\eta IL$; however this is an arrow in $\sf C$, so in the end, the equality to prove should be $IL\eta=\eta IL$ right?

I've managed to see that such equality is equivalent to $LI\epsilon=\epsilon LI$, that should be more convenient since we know  that the counit is an isomorphism, as $I$ is fully faithful. So it seems that in general, for any adjunction $L\dashv I$ whose counit is an isomorphism, it holds $LI\epsilon=\epsilon LI$. Even if it seems  quite simple,  I can't prove it; is this a useful path or I just translated the problem to the counits without simplifying it?

Comment: I'm curious: how one does show that $IL\eta=\eta IL$ is equivalent to $LI\varepsilon=\varepsilon LI$? I don't see it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the claim to prove is $IL\eta = \eta IL$ as natural transformations $IL\to ILIL$; the claim now follows from the zig-zag identities or (which is sort of the same statement in a different dress) from the fact that any adjunction $L\dashv I$ with $I$ fully faithful induces an idempotent monad $T=IL$, and from one of the monad identities, precisely $\mu \circ \eta T = 1_T = \mu\circ T\eta$, you deduce $\eta T = \mu^{-1} = T\eta$ (because $T$ is idempotent if and only if $\mu$ is invertible, and inverses are unique).

Comment: What is $\mu $?

Comment: The multiplication of the monad $IL$.

Comment: Just to mention for the cat learner, this is the characterization of an idempotent monad \[[ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3149233/394668)].

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this is Exercise 4.5.vii, part (i), from Riehl's *[Category Theory in Context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)*. Fosco gave an answer based on monads, but monads aren't introduced in the book until Chapter 5. The following is an answer using only the zig-zag identities (explained by Riehl already before Sect. 4.5). In our case, these say
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon L\cdot L\eta&=1_L\\
I\varepsilon\cdot\eta I&=1_I.
\end{align*}
Since $\varepsilon$ is an iso, so are $\varepsilon L$ and $I\varepsilon$. As Riehl does, I will denote by $*$ to horizontal composition in the 2-category of categories. We have:
\begin{align*}
IL\eta&=I(L\eta)\\
&=I(\varepsilon L)^{-1}\\
&=1_I*(\varepsilon *1_L)^{-1}\\
&=1_I*(\varepsilon^{-1}*1_L^{-1})\\
&=(1_I^{-1}*\varepsilon^{-1})*1_L\\
&=(1_I*\varepsilon)^{-1}*1_L\\
&=(I\varepsilon)^{-1}L\\
&=(\eta I)L\\
&=\eta IL.
\end{align*}
(The fact that $*$ commutes with vertical inverses is a consequence of the middle four interchange law.)

Extra: One can show that $LI\varepsilon =\varepsilon LI$ in a similar fashion. Let $d\in\mathsf{D}$. Then $(LI\varepsilon)_d=LI\varepsilon_d=L\eta_{Id}^{-1}=(L\eta_{Id})^{-1}=\varepsilon_{LId}=(\varepsilon LI)_d$ (this time, we needed to evaluate at $d$ since not all components of $\eta$ are necessarily isos).